# Usage of gnu_errfmt option in bash

Tags: bash, shopt

I readed [GNU/Bash document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) but i can't understand or find any realworld usage example.

**gnu_errfmt**

> If set, shell error messages are written in the standard GNU error
> message format.

**When i try:**

```
└─$ shopt -u gnu_errfmt
└─$ no_command
-bash: no_command: command not found
└─$ shopt -s gnu_errfmt
└─$ no_command
-bash: no_command: command not found
```

May you please give me real usage purpose and example.

Comment: Try it in a script. See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n6263.